Jenkinsfile: use groovy to call GitHub API
I'm trying to add comment to my Pull Request in GitHub from Jenkins. I'm using shared library and have this method:
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

def call() {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'github-api-token', variable: 'GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN')]) {
        def apiUrl = "https://{GITHUB_URL}/api/v3/repos/{ORG}/{REPO}/issues/1/comments"
        
        def client = new groovyx.net.http.RESTClient(apiUrl)
        client.headers['Authorization'] = "token ${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
        client.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.github+json'
        def response = client.post(body: [body: "comment via jenkins method"] as JSON)
        
        if (response.status == 201) {
            println "Comment added successfully to Pull Request"
        } else {
            println "Failed to add comment to Pull Request. Status code: ${response.status}, Response: ${response.data}"
        }
    }
}

However, I'm getting error: unable to resolve class JSON  09:56:46   @ line 12, column 42. 09:56:46      response = client.post(body: [body: "co
removing as JSON leads to getting this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No encoder found for request content type */*
Could somebody give my any hints what am I doing wrong?

Have you tried important JSON? import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

Yeah, still gettin unable to resolve class JSON

To answer your immediate question, you need to specify the requestContentType parameter instead of trying to cast the body parameter:
def response = client.post(body: [body: "comment via jenkins method"],
                           requestContentType: groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON)

It's right there in the docs.
But why do you want to @Grab a third-party library (not recommended) instead of something that is likely already installed? Both github-api and okhttp-api are extremely common on Jenkins instances and use the same builder pattern as the http-builder module.
